# P5 play and how to create a game over screen after more than three enemy sprites have gone past the player and reached the bottom of the screen

Tags: javascript, sprite, p5.js, game-development

I have a game made with the p5.js play library where a player sprite shoots out bullets and takes out with these bullets an oncoming stream of enemy sprites. I wanted to have the game set to game over after 3 enemy sprites have reached down the bottom of the screen past the player and wasn't sure how to approach doing that.

```
let y = 0;

let spr;
let enemies;
let player;
let bullets = [];
let bullet;
let bulletsprite;

let score = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  
  bulletsprites = new Group()
  enemies = new Group()
  for(i = 0; i < 60; i++){  
  
  spr = createSprite(
  random(width), y, random(10, 40), random(10, 40));
  spr.shapeColor = color(random(255), random(255), random(255), random(255));
  spr.velocity.y = random(0.7, 2);
  enemies.add(spr); 
    
  }
  
  player = createSprite(50, 50, 40, 40);
  player.shapeColor = color(255);
 
}


function draw() {
  background(30);
  
  player.velocity.x = 
    (mouseX-player.position.x)*0.1;
  player.velocity.y = 
    (mouseY-player.position.y)*0.1;
  
  textSize(72);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  
  drawSprites();
  if (enemies.length > 0) {
    text(score, width/2, height/2);
  }
  else {
    text("you win!", width/2, height/2);
  }
  bulletsprites.overlap(enemies, getScore)
}



function mousePressed() {
  //bullets positions setting
  let bullet = {
    x: mouseX,
    y: mouseY,
  };
    
    bullets.push(bullet);
    bulletsprite = createSprite(bullet.x, bullet.y, 10);
    bulletsprite.velocity.y = -4;
    bulletsprites.add(bulletsprite)
}

function getScore(bullets, enemies) {
  enemies.remove();
  score += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make a counter which adds up every time an enemy reaches the bottom.

make a pause variable

make a gameOver function which will pause your game if the counter reaches 3.

put all the functions like enemies moving and game motions within a if(pause==false){} statement on your main loop.

in the gameOver function make whatever you want to end the game, it can be an animation, a menu, a black screen with a text, buttons, etc...

call this function in your "main loop"

sorry for not using code, I don't use p5 but the logical part is the important part :) good luck.